# Populating field(s) in a table with values derived out of VBA code

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-access-2010

I found some [neat code](http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0008.htm) (via [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168659/how-can-i-get-the-currently-logged-in-windows-user-in-access-vba/168682) actually) for getting the username of the user currently logged in to Windows.

Say I have a table called `AdminEntry`. I'd be looking to get the `AdminEntry` table set up as the recordsource of a form, so the user would do the data entry on that table via the form. Any record they create and complete data entry for would then also have their username stamped on that record so we can track what belongs to who.

Not sure how I would go about pushing that username string in to the table, or the best approach.

Perhaps if the `AdminEntry` table had the following fields:

```
| UserName | Field1 | Field2 |
|          |        |        |
```

The user could just use the form to do data entry on `Field1` and `Field2`:

```
| UserName | Field1 | Field2 |
|          |  data  |  data  |
```

And then an event on a **Save** button could perhaps pull through the username string in to the `UserName` field and prior to saving the full record in the `AdminEntry` table:

```
| UserName | Field1 | Field2 |
|   data   |  data  |  data  |
```

Haven't got a clue how to pull through that username string though, so would love some help/pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a text box, `txtUserName`, to the form and bind it to the `UserName` field.  You can set the text box's `.Visible` property to `No`.

Then assign the value from that `fOSUserName()` function to `txtUserName` from the form's before update event.  Note before update also occurs in conjunction with form insert, so this approach will store the current user name both when you add a new record and when you modify an existing record.

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    ' Me.txtUserName = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
    Me.txtUserName = fOSUserName
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @HansUp, works great! To anyone else reading: don't do what I did initially and bind the `txtUserName` textbox's control source to `=[UserName]`; make sure it's just `[UserName]` otherwise it won't be able to accept entries from anywhere else (and an error will pop-up). Quick question: the code you commented-out, is that just a simpler/alternative way of getting the username without the need of going through the `fOSUserName` method?

Comment: Yes, that `CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName` was present in my original code.  I substituted `fOSUserName` because I thought you wanted that instead.  But I left `"WScript.Network"` in there in case other readers are interested.  Either way works fine.

Comment: @MattHall FWIW, I would recommend the `WScript.Network` approach because the older code cited in your question uses 32-bit Windows API calls and it almost certainly won't compile in 64-bit Access as written. There might be some way to fiddle with it to get it to run, but it would be easier just to use an approach that avoids direct references to 32-bit Windows API functions.